# filter on a collection navigation property

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I have this Entity

```
public class EventoBarca
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int EventoID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int BarcaID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tesserato> Tesserati { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to filter the BarcaId where the EventoBarca has a specific EventoID and Tesserato has a specific TesseratoId

this is the query I'm using:

```
int ba = _db.ListEventiBarche.Include("Tesserati").Where(i => (i.Tesserati.Any(j => j.TesseratoID.ToString() == teid) && i.EventoID.ToString() == evid)).Select(i => i.BarcaID).FirstOrDefault();
```

but I receive this error message:
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

What is it wrong in my query ?

Comment: That error is not pointing to your query, `_db` has been disposed somehow, where is `_db` coming from? Dependency injection?

Comment: _db is just the db context

Comment: private SkipContext _db = new SkipContext();

Comment: Yes that&#39;s standard, but by the time you try to use it it&#39;s disposed. The problemyour having is elsewhere in you code.

Comment: If I use the code in debug mode step by step the error arose on that line of code. I'm also using an external application like LinqPad4 to test my queries and actually it didn't give me any problem

Comment: Yes it will be because it's disposed. If you have `_db` as a private variable and at anytime use it in a using block it will be disposed and all subsequent calls to it will fall.

Comment: ok, I understood what you mean... I'm probably using the same object instance before that line of code. thanks a lot